# Flutter Stripe does not show/present payment sheet

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, stripes

In my flutter project, I'm attempting to integrate a Stripe payment using **flutter_stripe** package.
I've intialize and configured correctly. But when trying to present paymentSheet nothing showing or happen. There's also no error cause. As it stuck at the line and not run code after that. I've also tried plugin simple example code as well but not work as i want. Any help will be appreciated.

main.dart

```
  Stripe.publishableKey = StripeService.publishableKey;
  Stripe.merchantIdentifier = 'merchant.flutter.stripe.test';
  Stripe.urlScheme = 'flutterstripe';
  await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

service.dart

```
Future<void> initPaymentSheet() async {
try {
  // 1. create payment intent on the server
  final paymentSheetData = await createPaymentIntent("1200", 'usd');
  print("payment intent created");

  // create some billingdetails
  final billingDetails = BillingDetails(
    email: 'email@stripe.com',
    phone: '+48888000888',
    address: Address(
      city: 'Houston',
      country: 'US',
      line1: '1459  Circle Drive',
      line2: '',
      state: 'Texas',
      postalCode: '77063',
    ),
  ); // mocked data for tests

 // 2. initialize the payment sheet
  await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
      paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
    applePay: true,
    googlePay: true,
    style: ThemeMode.dark,
    testEnv: true,
    merchantCountryCode: 'US',
    merchantDisplayName: 'Prospects',
    customerId: paymentSheetData!['customer'],
    paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentSheetData['paymentIntent'],
    customerEphemeralKeySecret: paymentSheetData['ephemeralKey'],
  ));
  print("payment sheet created");

  await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();

  print("after payment sheet presented");
} on Exception catch (e) {
  if (e is StripeException) {
    print("Error from Stripe: ${e.error.localizedMessage}");
  } else {
    print("Unforeseen error: ${e}");
  }
  rethrow;
}
```

}

output

> I/flutter (14987): payment intent created
> I/flutter (14987): payment sheet created

Comment: Are you getting the correct data from the back-end server?

Comment: I'd suggest you reach out to the developers/community via their github issues to see if they can suggest what might help here: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues

Comment: @vishnuanilkumar backend response https://textdoc.co/akteSsynvKdZREmP 
would u plz check and confirm if anything missing or is it correct?

Comment: @Dr_Usman, can you make sure 'customer', 'paymentIntent', 'ephemeralKey' are present in the response of createPaymentIntent. If 3 of them are it will work, also you need to create customer in stripe dashboard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I check your backend response you are using "paymentIntent" instead of "client_secret", you should initialize your payment sheet as below

```
await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
  paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
    applePay: true,
    googlePay: true,
    style: ThemeMode.dark,
    testEnv: true,
    merchantCountryCode: 'US',
    merchantDisplayName: 'Prospects',
    customerId: paymentSheetData!['customer'],
    paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentSheetData['client_secret'],
    customerEphemeralKeySecret: paymentSheetData['ephemeralKey'],
));
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution, there's something incorrect parameter value while initialize the payment sheet

### Wrong

```
paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentSheetData['paymentIntent'],
```

### Correct

```
paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData!['client_secret'],
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure to enter the Stripe.stripeAccountId value if you're using stripe connect, otherwise it'll error out.

````
 Stripe.stripeAccountId = paymentDetails.stripe_account_id;

      await Stripe.instance.applySettings();

      if (Stripe.stripeAccountId == '') {
        print(
            'You need to connect your Stripe account via the dashboard.');
        return;
      }
    ```
````